# Play one Audio at the time in VueJS

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, audio

I'm trying to play one audio at the sime while having different audio source in a v-for.
What i'm trying to do is when i click on play on one track, the one playing is paused etc.

I tried to togglePLay with a click on a button outside  but couldn't paused the sound

he is my template code, getting the source from an api call to deezer and getting them as prop

```
<template>
  <div>
  <div v-for="(track,index) in listTrack" :key="track.title">
    <div>
      <p class="pl-5">
        {{track.track_position}} - {{track.title}}
        <Notation :idTrack="track.id" :index="index" :connectedUserorNot="ifConnected"></Notation>
      </p>
      <audio controls>
        <source :src="track.preview" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

thx

Comment: have you tried creating a single self contained audio player component that takes a track as a prop, and then imported that component into the one you show?

Comment: why did i not think of that, i created a component but as it is place in a v-for, each track is independant and i can play each one. I miss the element to stop all of them

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun little challenge, thank you! Just tried replicating your code in a code sand box. Other than changing

```
<audio controls>
    <source :src="track.preview" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

to

```
<audio 
    controls
    :src="track.preview" 
    type="audio/mpeg"
>
</audio>
```

The rest of my solution was to hook into the play event of the audio element and using $ref to target the audio players pause function like so:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img width="25%" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <h1>Orginal code example</h1>
    <div v-for="track in listTrack" :key="track.title">
      <div>
        <audio
          :ref="`player-${track.title}`"
          controls
          :src="track.audioURL"
          type="audio/mpeg"
          @play="stopOthers(track.title)"
        ></audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      listTrack: [
        {
          audioURL:
            "http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3",
          title: "test"
        },
        {
          audioURL:
            "http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3",
          title: "test2"
        },
        {
          audioURL:
            "http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3",
          title: "test3"
        },
        {
          audioURL:
            "http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3",
          title: "test4"
        }
      ],
      currentTrack: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    stopOthers(newTrack) {

      if (this.currentTrack) {
        let refName = `player-${this.currentTrack}`;
        let player = this.$refs[refName][0];
        player.pause();
      }
      this.currentTrack = newTrack;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[image: Edit Answer for Reevan]

Hopefully I under stood you question correctly, and this solution works for you

Comment: I don't know the audio of a track as it is in a v-for of an api and i get the data from a prop.
I added a switch between 2 button, on to play and the other to stop, so i'm trying to get the one playing in the play() methods through the index but it doesn't stop

Comment: I tried your way, and it works, now I just have to do the same with a button and not the control of the audio that i can't customize

Answer (score 0):

i deleted controls of the audio and handle this by using btn on my own

```
  stopOthers(newTrack, index) {
      if(this.currentTrack == null ){
        let refName = `player-${newTrack}`;
        let player = this.$refs[refName][0];
        player.play();
        this.playerPlaying = player
        this.currentTrack = newTrack;
        this.thisTrackisPlaying = true
        this.indexOfTrack  = index
      } else if (this.currentTrack == newTrack) {
        var current = this.currentTrack
        let refName = `player-${current}`;
        let player = this.$refs[refName][0];
        this.currentTrack = null;
        this.playerPlaying = player
        player.pause();
        player.currentTime = 0
        this.thisTrackisPlaying = false
      }
      else if (this.currentTrack != newTrack) {
        var player2 = this.playerPlaying
        player2.pause()
        this.thisTrackisPlaying = false
        let refName = `player-${newTrack}`;
        let player = this.$refs[refName][0];
        this.playerPlaying = player
        player.play();
        this.currentTrack = newTrack;
        this.thisTrackisPlaying = true
        this.indexOfTrack  = index
      }

    //  this.currentTrack = newTrack;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to the `player.pause();` line from Chad Roberts' answer below because I couldn't get the players to restart after I paused them:

```
if (newTrack == this.currentTrack) {} else {player.pause()}
```

I also used urls instead of track titles for the `stopOthers` argument and refs because they were more unique.

This solution should also work for videos.